# Checkbox becomes unchecked when another checkbox becomes checked django

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox, django-views

I have two checkboxes, in two different HTML forms. In my template , when a checkbox is clicked, its value gets submitted to the view function and saved to the database and then that checkbox becomes an icon using an if else statement.

Form snippet:

```
<form id='ISBN_form' action="{%url 'tracker:bookSteps' book_page.id%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="columns is-mobile">
        {% if book_progress.ISBNsent == 'True' %}
        <div class="content column is-5">
            <label class="checkbox" dir="rtl">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-check has-text-success"></i>
                تم التسليم
            </label>
        </div>
        {%else%}
        <div class="content column is-5">
            <label class="checkbox" dir="rtl">
                <input type="checkbox" name="ISBNsent" id="ISBNsent" value="True" onchange="submitCheckbox();">
                    تم التسليم
            </label>
        </div>
        {%endif%}
    </div>
</form>
```

This works great and the value gets saved to database and it becomes an icon in the html page.

But the problem is that when I check a checkbox the other one becomes unchecked and vice versa, only in the html template but in the database it stays checked. I don't know where the problem is and why this behavior is happening while I have the if else and the value that is being checked is from the database so why it gets unchecked again?

my view function:

```
def bookSteps(request,book_id):
   book_page = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
   print(book_page.id)
   book_progress = Progress()
   book_progress = Progress.objects.get(BookID=book_id)
   if request.method == 'POST': 
      print(request.POST)
      if 'ISBNsent' in request.POST:
         ISBNsent=request.POST.get("ISBNsent")
         book_progress.ISBNsent=ISBNsent
         sentDate=datetime.datetime.now()
         book_progress.ISBN_sentDate =sentDate.date() 
         book_progress.save()
         #return HttpResponseRedirect (reverse('dashboard'))
      elif 'ISBNdelivered' in request.POST:
         ISBNdelivered=request.POST.get("ISBNdelivered")  
         book_progress.ISBNdelivered=ISBNdelivered
         deliveredDate=datetime.datetime.now()
         book_progress.ISBN_deliveredDate =deliveredDate.date() 
         book_progress.save()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because label is not a input field. Therefore, label data won't submitted.

In this case, my suggestion

load the field with label as hidden field.

```
  {% if book_progress.ISBNsent == 'True' %}
                          <div class="content column is-5">
                            <label class="checkbox" dir="rtl">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-check has-text-success"></i>
                              تم التسليم
                            </label>
                            <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="ISBNsent" value="True">
                            </div>
```

Comment: I don't want the icon to be submitted. I want that if the value of ISBN_sent is True then show the icon instead of a real checkbox , else , show the checkbox so the user can click on it. And that works , but the problem is when i click on the next checkbox the first checkbox gets empty again. Do you think this has to do with the render ?